# Running all numeric variables through a macro

Tags: sas

```
%macro numstats(var = ,file=, format=);
data _null_;
z = find("&var.",'date');
call symput('myeval',z);
run;

%if &myeval. > 0 Or &var. = lpi %then %do;
  Proc SQL;
  create table &var as  
  select "&var." as Varname Length = 35, min(a.&var.) as Minimum FORMAT=&format., max(a.&var.) as Maximum FORMAT=&format., 
  ROUND(avg(a.&var.),.01) as Mean, count(*) as Total_Count,x.Count_Null, y.Count_Zero
  from &file. a
  left join (select "&var." as Var, count(*) as Count_Null from &file.
            where &var = .) x
  on "&var." = x.var
  left join (select "&var." as Var, count(&var.) as Count_Zero from &file.
            where &var  = 0) y
  on "&var." = y.var
  where &var. > 0
  ;
  quit;
  Data &var (rename=(MyNewVar = Minimum MyNewVar2 = Maximum));
  Set &var;
  MyNewVar = Put(Minimum,Date9.);
  MyNewVar2 = Put(Maximum,Date9.);
  *if MyNewVar < 0 then MyNewVar = "";
  *if MyNewVar2 < 0 then MyNewVar2 = "";
  drop Minimum Maximum;
  *format myNewVar yymmddn8. myNewVar2 yymmddn8.;
  run;
%end;
%else %do;
  Proc SQL;
  create table &var as
  select "&var." as Varname Length = 35, min(a.&var.) as Minimum, max(a.&var.) as Maximum, 
  ROUND(avg(a.&var.),.01) as Mean, count(*) as Total_Count,x.Count_Null, y.Count_Zero
  from &file. a
  left join (select "&var." as Var, count(*) as Count_Null from &file.
            where &var = .) x
  on "&var." = x.var
  left join (select "&var." as Var, count(&var.) as Count_Zero from &file.
            where &var  = 0) y
  on "&var." = y.var
  where &var. > 0
  ;
  quit;
  Data &var (rename=(MyNewVar = Minimum MyNewVar2 = Maximum));
  Set &var;
  MyNewVar = Put(Minimum,$12.);
  MyNewVar2 = Put(Maximum,$12.);
  if MyNewVar < 0 then MyNewVar = "";
  if MyNewVar2 < 0 then MyNewVar2 = "";
  drop Minimum Maximum;
  run;
%end;
%mend numstats;
```

I have a macro set up that goes through a predefined variable (var) and checks to see whether it is numeric or date-numeric and then formats the statistics generated with the SQL code accordingly.

The code is working correctly. My issue is that the numeric variables need to be called out one by one. For example,

```
%numstats(var = originalprincipalbalance,file=work.filename);.
```

The file has many numeric columns and the columns will change from time to time. Is there a way to setup SAS for it to find all the numeric variables and run them through this macro without me having to call them out one by one?

I am hoping this would significantly cut down on someone having to error check all the variables in each file and make sure they are all being run on their own line of code. Also, I would have to have seventy+ lines of code that are essentially the same thing with the variable being the only thing that changes each time.

Please help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: SAS is very good at analysis of MANY variables with one PROC.  If you would show your input and desired output I think someone can show you how to do what you want with a couple of PROC steps for all \_NUMERIC\_ variables in a data set without referring to the variables by name.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed the second markup, it needed  a blank line to work.  It's great that you have shared your code.  Please share you input and desired output as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - as *data _null_* notes, this is probably a very overcomplicated solution to your problem; SAS is useful mostly for its built in tools.  Use them.

That said - the solution to the directly asked question is fairly straightforward.

You can obtain a list of the variables in a table from two sources which are effectively the same.  `SASHELP.VCOLUMN` and `dictionary.columns` contain the names, types, and other attributes of variables ("columns") in all of the tables you have in your various libnames (with some limitations on non-SAS datasets, such as ODBC tables or such).  `dictionary.columns` is available in `proc sql`, `sashelp.vcolumn` is available in a SAS data step (as a view).

So:

```
proc sql;
  select cats('%numstats(var=',name,',file=filename, format=',format,')')
    into :mcalllist separated by ' '
    from dictionary.columns
    where libname='WORK' and memname='MYDATA' and type='num';
quit;
```

For example, would create a macro variable `&mcalllist` which contained calls to that macro for all of your variables.  I don't know how you define filename - if it's all the same (and the same as the source dataset), then you can hardcode that and/or use a macro variable to define that both in the memname (which is the dataset name) and in the filename macro parameter.

Comment: Thank you, Joe! I am new to SAS and had not thought to use dictionary.columns as a reference for finding the variables. I was able to run through all the variables and put them into the macro using a slight variation of your code.